# numpy sort arrays based on last column values

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[5,9,44],
              [5,12,43],
              [5,33,11]])

b = np.sort(a,axis=0)

print(b) #not well

# [[ 5  9 11]
# [ 5 12 43]
# [ 5 33 44]]

#desired output:

#[[5,33,11],
# [5,12,43],
# [5,9,44]]
```

what numpy sort does it changes rows completely(ofcourse based on lower to highest), but i would like to keep rows untouched. I would like to sort rows based on last column value, yet rows and values in array must stay untouched. Is there any pythonic way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ind=np.argsort(a[:,-1])
b=a[ind]
```

**EDIT**
When you use `axis` in the sort, it sorts every column individually, what you want is to get indices of the sorted rows from the selected column (-1 is equivalent to the last column), and then reorder your original array.

Comment: That was fast,thank you.

Comment: some further explanation would be great!

Answer (score 2):

```
a[a[:,-1].argsort()]
```

may work for you

Comment: For accessing the last column, it's more robust to use `-1` as opposed to accessing from the front of a list, since the former scales to different shapes.